# Is there a way of finding out which Chrome Extensions API methods support Promises?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, promise

I just recently started programming a Chrome extension and after trying around a lot and failing, I decided to read almost the entire [Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions), maybe should have done that earlier. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I decided I want to use Promises and read the page ["Using promises"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/promises/).

Where it says:

> "Not all methods in extensions APIs support promises. Sometimes that's
> because we haven't added promise support on the method yet; in many
> cases it's because using a promise isn't feasible for the method."

It also gives some examples of what API methods can and cannot be used with Promises.

**What I could not find was a way to find out which methods support Promises and which do not.**

For example:
[chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-create) supports Promises, but I cannot seem to find something indicating that in the docs.

First StackOverflow question so pls be gentle with me, help is very appreciated. :P

Comment: If the function has a `callback` parameter it's likely that it doesn't support Promises yet (because callbacks were used before promises were a thing). You can also check the return value; a function that supports promises always returns a Promise object. When in doubt, just log the function's return value.

Comment: Callbacks will be supported along with Promise so it's not an indicator. ManifestV3 is still in development so just try to use the API with a Promise and expect things to break. After that either promisify the API yourself or wait until ManifestV3 is finished.

Comment: FWIW you can view the current state of some API (as implemented in Chrome Canary or Chromium trunk) in [source code](https://source.chromium.org/search?q=file:extensions%20file:idl%20supportsPromises).

Comment: Ty @wOxxOm that's's a start at least. Although, I cannot find the aforementioned tabs.create method in the link you posted.

Comment: Look for `returns_async` in the source code for the rest of API. See also https://crbug.com/328932

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I could find myself is on an old Question with a [recent update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66321636/15531947) listing all the supported APIs with reference.